# Google sheets script to move rows to new sheet based on checkbox - rows keep moving to bottom of sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

I have a script to move a row to my 2nd sheet based on a checkbox. When it moves into the 2nd sheet it is moved to the next empty row.

However, when I uncheck the box to move it back to the original sheet (sheet 1), the row is moved all the wat to the bottom of the spreadsheet (row number 1000) when I want it to move to the next empty row.

Here is my current script (this is my first time using scripts - I took this off of google):

```
function onEdit() {


  var mainSheet = "Sheet1";
  var sheetToMoveTheRow = "Sheet2";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && range.getColumn() == 17 && range.getValue() == true) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(sheet.getName() == "Sheet2" && range.getColumn() == 17 && range.getValue() == false) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you wish to save the row positions?

Comment: In the next available empty row. (so not the very bottom of the spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you deselect a checkbox in any row on Sheet2, the corresponding row is moved to the bottom of Sheet1. This is because unchecked checkboxes in column 17 extend all the way to the last row, and Apps Script treats checkboxes as values in the sheet. As a result, when the .getLastRow() method is called on Sheet1, the script returns the last row containing a checkbox.

To address this issue, you can calculate the last row with actual values by considering a column where every row contains data from the first row to the most recent row with real values. You can accomplish this by incorporating the following two lines of code (using Columna A as an example):

```
const aVals = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
const targetRow = aVals.filter(String).length + 1;
```

You can include those two line in your else if section like this:

```
else if(sheet.getName() == "Sheet2" && range.getColumn() == 17 && range.getValue() == false) {
 var row = range.getRow();
 var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 const aVals = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 const targetRow = aVals.filter(String).length + 1;
 var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow , 1);
 sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
 sheet.deleteRow(row);
}
```